# CQRS - applying command based on decision from multiple projections

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

Question is related to CQRS - I have user that wants to order something from web and is presented with GUI showing his balance = 100$ and stock = 1 item. Let's say we have 2 services here `AccountService` and `StockService` with separate concerns. In order to generate GUI for client third service `AggregatorService` listens to domain events from `AccountService` and `StockService`, projects a view and creates GUI for clients.

When user decides to order this item, he clicks a button and Command for order is sent to `AccountService`. Here we load `AccountAggregate` in order to decrease balance for the price of the item that needs to be ordered. But before I can do this, I have to check if the item is still available (or somehow to reserve it). Only thing that comes up to my mind is:

- Read current stock of the item from read model of `StockService`, but what can happen is that other services read model is updated just a second after I read it (e.g. somebody bought the item, so actual stock is =0. but read model still has =1).
- Before decreasing a balance call some method on `StockService` to reserve the item for some time. If order is not successful (e.g. no enough funds on balance, I would have to un-reserve it somehow). This needs to be some sync-REST call and it is probably slower than some async solution (if any).

Are there any best practices for this kind of use-case?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, depending on whether you embrace eventual consistency or not.

Using immediate consistency I would have an OrderService that receives the order request and it makes async calls to AccountService.ReservePayment() and StockService.ReserveStock().  If either of those fail you call AccountService.UndoReservePayment() and StockService.UndoReserveStock().  If both succeed you call AccountService.CompleteReservePayment() and StockService.CompleteReserveStock(). Make sure each reservation should have a timestamp on it so a daemon process can occasionally run and Undo any reserves that are older than an hour or so.

This approach makes the user wait until both those services complete.  If either the StockService or the AccountService are slow, the user experience is slow.  I suggest a better way to do this is the eventual consistency approach which gives the user a very fast experience at the expense of receiving failure messages after the fact.

With eventual consistency you assume they have enough credit and you have enough inventory, and in response to their order request you immediately send back a success message.  The user is happy and they go along to buy more stuff.

The OrderCreated event is then handled asynchronously to reserve stock and credit as described above.  However, since there is no time pressure to reply to the waiting user you don’t have to scale up to handle as high a throughput.  If the credit check and stock check take a minute or two, the user doesn’t care because he’s off doing other things.

The price you pay here is that the user may get a success message at the time of order submission, then a few minutes later get an email saying the sale didn’t go through after all because there’s no stock.  This is what many large retailers do, including Amazon, Target, Walmart, etc.  Eventual consistency can go a long way towards easing the load and cost of the back end.

Comment: Just want to add that "eventually consistent" method would need some process that manages business transaction and common name for such process is Saga or ProcessManager.

Comment: Do you have example of this "success message" since this worries me the most? I guess user should be somehow notified that his order can fail? Otherwise it could be a problem that he relies on this one. - Do you have some link to see how Amazon, Target, etc. deals with this one?

Comment: By "success message" i just meant a text notification to the user that their order was successful.  The failure message should be processed and emails within a minute or two even with eventual consistency, so for casual purchases that should be sufficient.  If you're selling something where there are big adverse effects for the delayed error notification, you can tell the user "Your order submitted - look for a confirmation soon" and then send them a success or fail message when you're ready.  If you MUST be immediately consistent, be prepared to scale up.

Comment: BTW, I don't have any examples of Amazon or Target messages, but I went to a talk by the Target CTO and he said that's how they do things.  Amazon has echoed the same idea.  The message they send is just an "oops! your order has been delayed.  please look for it in 2 weeks"